# shell: dividing columns using awk stops if there is a non integer found

Tags: shell-script, awk

I have a file called `file.csv` with multiple rows and columns like this:

```
API,20042017-01:00,341701,341701,480692,480692
API,20042017-02:00,293058,293058,415459,415459
API,20042017-03:00,272692,272692,388942,388942
API,20042017-04:00,279117,279115,399361,399361
API,20042017-05:00,345947,345945,495306,495306
```

and I want to calculate the percent value by multiplying the ratio of column 4 to column 3 by 100, so I typed in the following command:

```
awk -F, '{ print $1, $2, $3, $4, ($4/$3*100), $5, $6 }' file.csv
```

which gives me the required output:

```
API,20042017-01:00,341701,341701,100,480692,480692
API,20042017-02:00,293058,293058,100,415459,415459
API,20042017-03:00,272692,272692,100,388942,388942
API,20042017-04:00,279117,279115,100,399361,399361
API,20042017-05:00,345947,345945,100,495306,495306
```

but when there's a non integer in column 3, it gives me a error saying:

```
awk: (FILENAME=file.csv FNR=3) fatal: division by zero attempted
```

and stops counting the rest of the rows.

How could I make it continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask awk to validate if a field is a number by using ~ /^[0-9]+/.

Here's a little shell script that demonstrates this:

```
[root@tiny ~]# cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

INPUT="API,20042017-01:00,341701,341701,100,480692,480692
API,20042017-02:00,293058,293058,100,415459,415459
API,20042017-03:00,272692,272692,100,388942,388942
API,20042017-04:00,279117,279115,100,399361,399361
API,20042017-04:00,279117,FRED,100,399361,399361
API,20042017-05:00,345947,345945,100,495306,495306"

echo "$INPUT" | awk -F, '$3 ~ /^[0-9]+/ && $4  ~ /^[0-9]+/ { print $1, $2, $3, $4, ($4/$3*100), $5, $6 }'

[root@tiny ~]# ./test.sh
API 20042017-01:00 341701 341701 100 100 480692
API 20042017-02:00 293058 293058 100 100 415459
API 20042017-03:00 272692 272692 100 100 388942
API 20042017-04:00 279117 279115 99.9993 100 399361
API 20042017-05:00 345947 345945 99.9994 100 495306
[root@tiny ~]#
```

Comment: It works,, actually i am getting FATAL error if there is a zero value also "awk: (FILENAME=- FNR=2) fatal: division by zero attempted", hence i have used "'$3 ~ /^[1-9]+/ && $4  ~ /^[1-9]+/".. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That won't match anything with a zero in it at all.  What do you want to happen when you find something invalid?

Comment: you could use something like `$3 * 1 == $3 && $3 != 0 { ... }`.